# Javascript malfunction in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

[Here is a demo](http://cruisear.com/demo/1) In short brief: 
If somebody clicks on change text `next()` function will be triggered.

`next()` function sends the relative data to ajax_next_track.php and retrieves a random data.

Then it replaces texts in `artist_name` and `track_name` spans with the random data.

These all works fine in Firefox and Chrome. However, it doesn't in Internet Explorer. If you click on change text more than two times with different browsers you can see the problem.

In other browsers, there will be an operation time with 'loading...' text in screen; but it happens immediately with no operation time in internet explorer.

Function next() can not send the data to ajax file.

So, how can i fix it?

Thanks is advance.

```
    function next(tags)
    {
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = 'ajax_next_track.php?tags=' + tags;
        hr.open("GET", url, true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) 
            {   
               var return_data = hr.responseText;
               jsonObj = JSON.parse(return_data);
               document.getElementById("artist_name").innerHTML = jsonObj.artist_name;
               document.getElementById("track_name").innerHTML = jsonObj.track_name;
               document.getElementById("name").title = 'play '+jsonObj.artist_name+' - '+jsonObj.track_name+' radio';

            else
            {

            }
        }

        document.getElementById("track_name").innerHTML = 'loading...';
        document.getElementById("artist_name").innerHTML = '';
        hr.send(null); 
}
```

---

```
<div id="player">
    <div id="playPauseOutDiv" onclick="pause();">

    </div>
        <div id="artist_track">
            <span id="artist_name">gerry rafferty</span> 
            <span id="track_name">baker street</span>
        </div>
    </a>

    <div id="ikinciSatir">
        <a id="changeSong" title="Shuffle" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="next('3871');">Change</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can not send the data to ajax file"?  Do you mean `next` isn't getting called?  Or it's called and there is some error?  If the former, we need to see how it's being invoked.  If the latter, we need to see the error.

Comment: @PaulTomblin i have delete and fix the part with id name. But the main problem is still there; and i have added html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same problem just 2 days ago. I was using IE8, and subsequent ajax call wasn't really made but IE8 try to use cache instead.

I found this on ajax documentation page

By default, requests are always issued, but the browser may serve results out of its `cache`. To disallow use of the cached results, set `cache` to `false`. To cause the request to report failure if the asset has not been modified since the last request, set ifModified to true.

Try if it helps. Here's the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, IE caches the JSON file and gets 304 Not Modified response instead of 200 OK each time after the 1st one.

The easiest workaround for this that doesn't need to change server side settings is to add some random parameter to the requested URL on each request, e.g.

```
var url = 'ajax_next_track.php?tags=' + tags + '&nocache=' + Math.random();
```

Comment: The "reason" that IE caches the response is that's what the HTTP standard (RFC 2616) says to do.

Comment: @EricLaw, thanks for the clarification. But what is the reason that other browsers get 200 OK response? I tried to find the difference between the HTTP headers displayed by Firebug and IE Dev. Tools, respectively, but didn't notice it...

Comment: In some cases, other browsers don't treat XHR cacheability according to the standards. Without the exact repro (particularly the response headers), I can't say for sure what you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

The error in IE's debugger says `line 40 document.getElementById("name") is null or not an object.`  I see spans named "artist_name" and "track_name" in your html, but no "name".

Comment: i have deleted and fixed the part whose id is name; but the main problem is still there.

Comment: I retried it, and it's working fine, except your ajax function is returning the same album every time.  That problem is on the server side, not on the code you've posted.

Comment: It is impossible that returning same track in every try. Because there are thousands of tracks. If you try it with other browsers you will see the problem. Also in other browsers, there will be an operation time with loading... text in screen; but it happens immediately with no operation time in internet explorer.